# what's the differnece between the 'gulp default task' and 'run-sequence npm modules'?

Tags: gulp, run-sequence

what's the difference between using 'gulp default task' and 'run-sequence npm modules if i have two tasks to execute,the result was the same.so i have no idea why should use 'run-sequence'?

1.gulp default task
`gulp.task('default',['task1','task2']);`

2.'run sequence npm modules'
`var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
    gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
        runSequence('task1', 'task2', callback);
    });`

i'm new in gulp,i saw the tutorial video online,and they teach to use 'run-sequence module' to advance the gulp skill,so i have got the question.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `task1` and `task2` are ran in parallel. In the second case, `task2` is ran after `task1` finishes.

You'd want to use `run-sequence` when a task depends on the result of another task.

To achieve this in gulp@3, you can also express this with task dependencies :

```
gulp.task('task2', ['task1'], function() {/* task definition */})
```

Here `task1` is defined as a dependency for `task2`, so `task2` won't execute until `task1` is finished.

Comment: I got it.Thanks a lot, your explanation is very clear.